# How to move prev/next of an Object of Objects (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Please consider the following JSON object:

```
Object {
    [i24] => Object {
                [name] => Mike
                [gender] => male
             }
    [i26] => Object {
                [name] => John
                [gender] => male
             }
    [i32] => Object {
                [name] => Mary
                [gender] => female
             }
}
```

How do I move the pointer to the previous/next item in the main object? Alternatively (perhaps even better), how can I get X-th object? eg. in the format of `jsonObject[X]`

Comment: Turn it into an array?

Comment: Please format it as JSON at least

Comment: @Bergi `Please consider the following JSON object:` :)

Comment: @Petroff: Well, yes, saying "the following JSON object" and then not posting any JSON doesn't make any sense, does it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'll answer this one myself :)

The solution is to use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var keysArray = Object.keys(JSONobject);

//to get the 2nd item of object
var secondObj = JSONobject[keysArray[1]];  // this will return i26 in given example.
```

Comment: Or just keep the original array as per your previous question?? looks like you are just making the data much harder to work with by using an object